# Merge [cloudera-sentry] with [apache-sentry]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge [cloudera-sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudera-sentry) (29 questions) with [apache-sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-sentry) (24 questions) as Cloudera successfully migrated the project to Apache.  This is obvious from looking at the [Sentry Project History](https://sentry.apache.org/general/history.html):

> - 2012 - Development of Cloudera Access (later renamed to Sentry) starts
> - 2013 - Cloudera Access is deployed in production at customers and renamed Sentry
> - Jul 29, 2013 Sentry Proposal sent to Apache Incubator
> - Aug 8, 2013 Sentry accepted into the Apache Incubator
> - Sep 25, 2013 Apache Sentry version 1.2.0 is released
> - May 13, 2014 Apache Sentry version 1.3.0 is released
> - Aug 18, 2014 Apache Sentry version 1.4.0 is released
> - Jul 15, 2015 Apache Sentry version 1.5.1 is released
> - Sep 21, 2015 Apache Sentry version 1.6.0 is released